# airflow dag never gets triggered with a dynamic start_date

Tags: airflow

I have set the dag's arguments as this:

```
today = datetime.now().date()
default_args = {'owner': 'Mark',
                'depends_on_past': False,
                'start_date': datetime(today.year,today.month,today.day,10,0),
                'retries': 3,
                'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
                'schedule_interval': '@daily'}
```

The intent was to start the job every at 10 am. However, I find nothing has been triggered ever since.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a wrong setup. The `start_date` should be fixed, and never dynamically determined. This is explicitly stated in Airflow official FAQ ([What's the deal with `start_date`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date)):

> We recommend against using dynamic values as `start_date`, especially `datetime.now()` as it can be quite confusing. The task is triggered once the period closes, and in theory an `@hourly` DAG would never get to an hour after now as `now()` moves along.

You should put a fixed `start_date` (in the past), and then set the `schedule_interval` to be a cron expression meaning "everyday at 10" (i.e. `"0 10 * * *"`). I would do something like this:

```
default_args = {'owner': 'Mark',
                'depends_on_past': False,
                'start_date': dt.datetime(2020, 4, 8)
                'retries': 3,
                'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10),
                'schedule_interval': '0 10 * * *'}
```

For more info about `start_date` and `schedule_interval` refer to the official documentation, specifically this one about [Scheduling & Triggers](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.